# How show different paths for multiple servers in swagger?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I specify different paths for each option selected in the servers dropdown of the Swagger UI?

For example, let's say that I have this

```
{
"openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/v2"
    }
  ],

  [...]
}
```

And I want to show different paths based on what server the user selected on the dropdown:
[image]

e.g. if the user selected v1 then I want to show paths A, B, C
else if the user selected v2 then I want to show paths D, E, F.
Is it possible?

Comment: this is not possible in the current OpenAPI Specification, this is a feature request for the documentation software, in this case, Swagger UI.